# A more efficient method of blurring a small section of a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uigraphicscontext

I am wanting to capture a snapshot of a small area of the screen and apply a blur to it - albeit at 60fps - which is not possible with this code:

```
let rectangle = CGRect(x: -37, y: -153, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

captureSnapShotWithGaussianBlur(rect: rectangle)

public func captureSnapShotWithGaussianBlur(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {

      let SCREEN_SIZE_SCALE_FACTOR = UIScreen.main.scale
      let CROPPING_RECT = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 118*SCREEN_SIZE_SCALE_FACTOR, height: 66*SCREEN_SIZE_SCALE_FACTOR)

      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 118, height: 66), true, 0.0)

      backgroundView!.drawHierarchy(in: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)

      let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
      let ciimage: CIImage = CIImage(image: capturedImage)!

      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

      let gaussianfilter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur")!
      gaussianfilter.setDefaults()
      gaussianfilter.setValue(ciimage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
      gaussianfilter.setValue(10, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

      let outputImage: CIImage = gaussianfilter.outputImage!
      let finalImage: UIImage = UIImage(ciImage: outputImage.cropping(to: CROPPING_RECT), scale: SCREEN_SIZE_SCALE_FACTOR, orientation: UIImageOrientation.up)

      return finalImage

}
```

One of the problems I see with my code is that I think the Gaussian Blur is applied to the whole image (because of UIScreen.main.bounds used for the drawHierarchy rectangle).

I was hoping there was a way of doing a resizableSnapshotView() of the screen, then doing drawHierarchy in that view and extracting the image - alas, this does not work (although it seems to in the Simulator, but not on the phone where it simply renders black).

Any suggestions on how to make a more performant capture and blur method?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you using the built in snapshot function when you mentioned trying snapshotting it first ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried many combinations of methods using the built-in snapshot methods and then trying to use contents of that to create an image for blurring - to no avail.

The snapshot methods work fine in the Simulator, but render black on the actual phone. 

Apple - in the docs - says to use drawHierarchy for applying blur effects etc. 

Yet, I just want to be able to select an area of the screen and apply a blur to that in under 1/60th of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this extension to snapshot the view and blur this, it seems to work on both simulator and device:

```
extenstion UIView {
    /// A more efficient way to snapshot a UIView other than UIView.snapshot
///
/// - Returns: UIImage representing the snapshot of the UIView
public func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
    drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return snapshotImage
}

public func snapshotView() -> UIView? {
    if let snapshotImage = snapshotImage() {
        return UIImageView(image: snapshotImage)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, whilst this is a lot more re-usable than my code, is there a material difference that will affect performance? From what I can see, both are calling exactly the same methods and are doing the same thing - not being more performant. I should have used more performant, than more efficient. Thanks again.